# Get past time with php

Tags: php

Let's say i have date/time like this: `2012-02-05 18:58:19` now how can i get this time just `5min` ago? which would be `2012-02-05 18:53:19`
basicly i need to get 5 mins back from current time

Comment: all datetime related question have been answered before. please use the search function before asking.

Answer (score 7):

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-02-05 18:58:19');
$dt->modify('-5 minutes');
```

Now you can use $dt->format to display it in the format you need.

Answer (score 1):

I was used to simply `strtotime('-5 minutes', $date)`

Full example:

```
$now = time();
$past = strtotime('-5 minutes', $now);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $past);
```